# How to Connect 3 Networks With Ethernet and WIFi/VPN?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have two computers on a robot that are directly connected via Ethernet. Called" Magni" and "Jetson". Magni is connected to a wireless network. On this wireless network, there is a third computer "PC" that is connected to the Magni via Wireguard VPN.

[Picture of Network Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvHZp.jpg)

The goal is to be able to send and receive messages from all components of the system to one another. The Magni - Jetson and Magni - PC pairs can ping, discover, and publish to each other. The issue I am having is communication between my PC and the Jetson. I attempted to do some IP forwarding. Where first on the jetson I added a route from the static 192.168.131.1 IP to the Magni's VPN 10.0.0.161. After doing so I am able to ping the Magni's VPN address 10.0.0.161 from the jetson.

```
sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0  netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.131.1
```

Then on my PC, I attempted to add a similar route...

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.131.0  netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.161
```

From my PC I then tried to communicate with the jetson (via ping). However, I am not able to successfully communicate with the Jetson. From the PC when trying to ping the Jetson, I get this error with my current set up.

```
PING 192.168.131.2 (10.0.0.66) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.66 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Required key not available
```

I have also tried other routes to no avail. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction as to how to resolve this issue as I am not too experienced in networking.

PC's Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination   Gateway     Genmask       Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0           10.147.x.x      0.0.0.0         UG   600    0        0  wlp2s0

10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0

10.147.x.x      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

169.xxx.x.x     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0

192.168.131.0   10.0.0.161      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 wg0
```

Magni's Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         10.147.x.x      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0

10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0

10.19.xxx.xxx   10.147.x.x      255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlan0

10.147.x.x      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     600    0        0 wlan0

192.168.131.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enxb827eb452fa3
```

Jetson's Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

10.0.0.0           192.168.131.1   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0

169.xxx.x.x       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0

192.168.131.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```